# How to get randomly arranged image in Mathematica?

Tags: random, image, alignment

I'm now thinking about randomly arrangement of the imported image.
After importing 2 hand-written images, image1 and image2, I want to make each 5 copys and randomly arrange them in one graph, i.e. totally 10 images are in a single graph.
It is much better if the 10 images are in random rotation angle, random enlargement(shrink), random places.
I found ImageTransformation command and ImageResize command for rotation and enlargement, but I couldn't find the command for setting image coordinates to several images...

Is it possible to do such a thing in Mathematica? If someone know how to do this, or whether it is possible or not, please tell me.

Comment: `ImageTransformation` includes translation too. What have you tried until now?

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. Since I don't know how to upload image here, I'd like to call imported images, as imA and imB.

Comment: im1 = Table[imA, 5]
    theta1 = RandomReal[{1, 360}, 5];
    enlarge1 = RandomReal[{50, 100}, 5];
    ir1 = ImageRotate[im1[[#]], theta1[[#]]] & /@ Range[5];
(*After rotating, a strange Frame appear around each image, though...*)

  size1 = ImageResize[ir1[[#]], enlarge1[[#]]] & /@ Range[5];

Comment: Just show the two examplary images in your question, to be able to copy the images to Mathematica

Comment: (*I also did same thing to imB,*)
im2 = Table[imB, 5]
theta2 = RandomReal[{1, 360}, 5];
enlarge2 = RandomReal[{50, 100}, 5];
ir2 = ImageRotate[im2[[#]], theta2[[#]]] & /@ Range[5];

Comment: (*Then, I tried to scatter these 10 images in one large picture.
I want to give random coordinate to each image, assuming for \
example  1000x1000 pixel image. The protruding place should be cut.
The codes below is just trying, but they don't work... *)
coordinate1 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1000}, 2], 5]
ImageCompose[size1[[1]], size1[[2]], coordinate1[[1]]]

Comment: Sorry for not being able to attach images, but as an example image, the logo of Mathematica would be fine.https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html

Comment: Or how about making some shape and change it to "image"? I found the following example in command help of "Polygon";       Row[Reap[
   Table[Table[
     If[CoprimeQ[p, q], 
      Sow[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightGreen, ngon[p, q]}, 
        ImageSize -> 70]]], {q, 2, p/2}], {p, 5, 12}]][[2, 1]]]

Comment: You might create a frame image `frame = Image[ConstantArray[1, {1000, 1000, 3}]];` and combine your images with `ImageCompose` ,`ImageAssemble`,...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's kind of you. However, when I tried the ImageCompose, the two images are overlapped each other...What I want to make is like this image...This image contains random place, random angle, random size of "star", although it is composed of only one image (not 2 different kinds mixture).              https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/stars-random-sizes-seamless-pattern-vector-30899368

Comment: And this image has 3 kinds of images with random place and random angle, but not random size.        https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/id/202847383?get_facets=1&order=relevance&safe_search=1&k=star+pattern%2C+stars+pattern%2C+space+doodle&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Azip_vector%5D=1&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aphoto%5D=1&clickref=1101lwBYBxtn&mv=affiliate&mv2=Freepik&as_camptype=&as_channel=affiliate&as_source=partnerize&as_campaign=Freepik&as_content=api&as_audience=idp&sdid=6WTV6YJ5

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144476/discussion-between-rani-and-ulrich-neumann).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a startup:

Define a frame in which you want to compose some pictures

```
frame = Image[ConstantArray[1, {1000, 1000, 3}]];
```

In the next step choose  examlary images

```
pic1=  Import["ExampleData/spikey.tiff"]
```

at several positions in the frame

```
pics = {pic1, pic1, pic1, pic1};
pos = RandomInteger[{1 , 1000}, {Length[pics], 2}]
ImageCompose[frame, pics, pos ]//Framed
```

[image]

The list `pics`might contain rotated, translated and scaled images.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!! This is the exact answer which I want :)   Thanks to your very kind answer, I could make the desired image with my handwritten images (successfully with random sizes and random shapes). It's very nice of you... Thanks again.